# I have an AA TREE c++ implementation source code and I need to put that code into a Win32 c++

Tags: c++, winapi, tree

I have an assignment to make a real application of AA tree. For now I have only the console application format and I can't convert into win32 project. I work in visual studio 2015. The teacher didn't bring us any content to learn just told us to to do it. Would you help me please? This is the code for console application :

```
 * C++ Program To Implement AA Tree
 */
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
/*
 * Node Declaration
 */
struct node
{
    int count, level;
    string key; 
    node *right;
    node *left;
    node *parent;
    node *root;
}*root;
 
/*
 * Class Declaration
 */
class AATree
{
    public:
        int lookup(string &);
        void skew(node *);
        bool split(node *);
        void rebal(node *);
        node *insert(node *,node *);
        void print(node *);
        int countnode(node *);
        AATree()
    {
            root = NULL;
        }
};
 
/*
 * Main: Contains Menu
 */
int main()
{
    AATree at;
    int ch;
    string x;
    ifstream fin ("test.txt");
    while (1)
    {
        cout<<"\n---------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"\nOperations on AA Tree"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n---------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"1.Insert String into the Tree"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.Print Tree Data"<<endl;
        cout<<"3.Total Tree Nodes"<<endl;
        cout<<"4.Exit"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter Your Choice: ";
        cin>>ch;
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 1:
            if (fin.is_open())
            {
                while (fin>>x)
                {
                    at.lookup(x);
                }
                fin.close();
            }
        break;
        case 2:
            cout<<"Elemets of AA Tree"<<endl;
            at.print(root);
            break;
        case 3:
            cout<<"Total number of nodes"<<endl;
            cout<<at.countnode(root)<<endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout<<"Exiting"<<endl;
            exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"Wrong Choice"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
/*
 * Insert String into the Tree
 */
int AATree::lookup(string &key)
{
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->key = key;
    temp->level = 1;
    temp->count = 0;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->parent = NULL;
    temp = insert(root, temp);
    return temp->count;
}
 
/*
 * Skew Tree
 */
 
void AATree::skew(node *temp)
{
    node *ptr = temp->left;
    if (temp->parent->left == temp)
        temp->parent->left = ptr;
    else
        temp->parent->right = ptr;
    ptr->parent = temp->parent;
    temp->parent = ptr;
    temp->left = ptr->right;
    if (temp->left != NULL)
        temp->left->parent = temp;
    ptr->right = temp;
    temp->level = (temp->left ? temp->left->level + 1 : 1);
}
 
/*
 * Splitting of AA Tree
 */
bool AATree::split(node *temp)
{
    node* ptr = temp->right;
    if (ptr && ptr->right && (ptr->right->level == temp->level))
    {
        if (temp->parent->left == temp)
            temp->parent->left = ptr;
        else
            temp->parent->right = ptr;
        ptr->parent = temp->parent;
        temp->parent = ptr;
        temp->right = ptr->left;
        if (temp->right != NULL)
            temp->right->parent = temp;
        ptr->left = temp;
        ptr->level = temp->level + 1;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
 
/*
 * Rebalancing of AA Tree
 */
void AATree::rebal(node* temp)
{
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->level = 1;
    for (temp = temp->parent; temp != root; temp = temp->parent)
    {
        if (temp->level != (temp->left ? temp->left->level + 1 : 1 ))
        {
            skew(temp);
            if (temp->right == NULL)
                temp = temp->parent;
            else if (temp->level != temp->right->level)
                temp = temp->parent;
        }
        if (temp->parent != root)
        {
            if (split(temp->parent) == false)
                break;
        }
    }
}
 
/*
 * Insert Function to insert string into the tree
 */
node* AATree::insert(node* temp, node* ins)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        ins->count = 1;
        ins->parent = NULL;
        ins->left = NULL;
        ins->right = NULL;
        root = ins;
        return root;
    }
    if (ins->key < temp->key)
    {
        if (temp->left)
            return insert(temp->left, ins);
        temp->left = ins;
        ins->parent = temp;
        ins->count = 1;
        rebal(ins);
        return ins;
    }
    if (ins->key > temp->key)
    {
        if (temp->right)
            return insert(temp->right, ins);
        temp->right = ins;
        ins->parent = temp;
        ins->count = 1;
        rebal(ins);
        return ins;
    }
    temp->count++;
    delete ins;
    return temp;
}
 
/*
 * Display Tree Elements
 */
void AATree::print(node* temp)
{
    if (!temp)
        return;
    print(temp->left);
    cout <<"Value: "<<temp->key << "  Count:" << temp->count;
    cout<<"  Level: "<<temp->level<<endl;
    print(temp->right);
}
 
/*
 * Count number of nodes in AA Tree
 */
int AATree::countnode(node* temp)
{
    if (!temp)
        return 0;
    int count = 1;
    count = count + countnode(temp->left);
    count = count + countnode(temp->right);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "win32 project"? Do you need a GUI? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve by making a "win32 project"?

Comment: Yeah a GUI, like a button for insert and make an insert, a button for remove ,etc .. i found some tutorials on youtube but can't help me... Please

Comment: The simplest way would be MFC with the visual studio IDE. That's all just drag and drop and adding event handlers to buttons. Some alternatives i'd look into are SFML, SDL, QT Creator, or just plain good ol' OpenGL. It really depends on what you need, there is no standard GUI library for c++.

Comment: And how I add event handlers to buttons? How I even add buttons? Or it's called bad luck because I can't find something on YouTube or Google to help me or  I accept a bad grade ..

Comment: Wait, your teacher is telling you to convert your console program into a GUI program without ever introducing any GUI concepts to you? Was there a GUI course as a requirement for this course? GUIs are not trivial things that you can throw onto a student without any prior introduction, and converting a console app to a GUI app isn't a trivial thing either, as the event handling must be changed completely. And most important, did your teacher mandate a specific GUI technology to you? If so, they should have taught it first...

Comment: @andlabs My teacher said here's your projects ... I have an real AA tree application , and she said just google it until you find something to build your app.. What she told us to help us is New -> Visual C++ -> Win32 Project -> Finish

Comment: That sounds more like they were instructing you on how to build the program. What was the actual assignment? Was it specifically to add a GUI on top of the code you provided? You should ask them to clarify.

Comment: I will, thank you!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To turn your C++ code to Visual C++(Windows environment) all you need to do is to change all of your std:char s and std:string s to std:wchar s and std::wstring s, because windows uses wide ('w') format for text in Unicode, i.e there can be more then 1 byte per char.

In everything else your code has nothing to do with Windows and windows api - you don't include any platform specific libraries or headers.

Comment: But I have to make a project like New -> Visual C++ -> Win32 Project. And there I have a template, I have just to modify there but I can't understand what's there.

Comment: There is nothing "Win" in your code. There is nothing to do with windows within your code. You need to do exactly as I said. Do it as Visual C++. If want it to be Win project all you need to do is change main to wmain. google it on MS website if you don't know what wmain is. And don't forget to accept my answer since its right.

Comment: I have to create an application which use the AA tree.

Comment: Yeah there's nothing " Win " because I make it first for console.. and now I don't understand how to put that thing into an application :(

Comment: @CalinOnaca You should not have marked this as the correct answer then.

Comment: @bedbad You are misreading the question. The OP wants to know how to convert their console application into a GUI application.

Comment: I'm not misreading anything the answer is correct. Please don't interfere if you don't understand neither the question or the answer.

Comment: @CalinOnaca Nobody will code windows GUI for you. Your source of reference is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @bedbad "For now I have only the console application format and I can't convert into win32 project." "Win32 Project" (or similar) is the name for the standard template in most IDEs for a GUI program made using the Win32 API (`CreateWindowEx()` and all that). And the comments in the question only talk about GUIs.

Comment: _"because windows uses wide ('w') format for text in Unicode,"_ That depends on project property settings. Not true in general!

Comment: @CalinOnaca Just do something using that API is not an assignment. You should ask specifically what the gui. You can google any win app code and copy paste it then

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you have no idea what you are talking about. all MS api use WCHAR as character of text. Project property settings have nothing to do with the code.

Comment: @andlabs you're right.. this is what i want ...

Comment: @andlabs "For now I have only the console application format and I can't convert into win32 project." Read this sentence again and realize there is no question mark in the end of it. The code provided will compile as a part of win32 project. To make it be able to mix together with windows functions you must exactly as I said.

Comment: @bedbad I can't just copy, because i need to use that console code into my project...

Comment: @CalinOnaca remove main and add it just as another source into your win32 proj. Then just call functions from it in your windows GUI code. that's it.

Comment: @bedbad First, πάντα ῥεῖ is right; Microsoft provides "ANSI" and "Unicode" versions of most of their API functions for historical reasons. It is entirely possible, though painful, to do everything manually or with UTF-8, so the project settings tell the header files to make functions default to Unicode instead of ANSI. MSDN has more on the issue. And as for "there is no question mark", just because it doesn't have a question mark does not mean it isn't the question; this is basic logic. And as for "you must exactly as I said", you did not say anything about GUI programming.

Comment: @bedbad Okay, thank you!

Comment: @CalinOnaca if your professor is leaving you in the cold about writing a GUI, and you want to use the Windows API, then you will need a tutorial on Windows GUI programming. Charles Petzold's "Programming Windows, 5th Edition" is still the de facto best book on the matter, but there are several online tutorials that can do just as good of a job, such as theForger's tutorials. I still suggest you ask them for clarification first.

Comment: I will try, but she's words : " I don't care, handle it! "

Comment: @andlabs "just because it doesn't have a question mark does not mean it isn't the question" No that's exactly what means by definition. 
"First, πάντα ῥεῖ is right; Microsoft provides "ANSI" and "Unicode" versions of most of their API functions for historical reasons"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn933214(v=vs.85).aspx

You both don't know what you are talking about. Find a single CHAR type in there and prove me wrong.  project properties have nothing to do with the text. they change the width of char - the thing that's controlled with L in L"string"

Comment: *"Find a single CHAR type in there and prove me wrong."* - Uhm... that was easy: [GetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212.aspx). And for those APIs that do provide an ANSI and Unicode implementation, the decision is made based on the preprocessor symbols `MBCS` and `UNICODE`. Those are commonly part of the project settings in Visual Studio.